# Know if a specific line is outputed with exec

Tags: php

I'm writing a small PHP script running on a Linux nginx server and I need to execute a jar file.  I managed to do this with the function `exec()` like this

```
exec("java -Xmx1G -jar /path/otp-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar --build /path/graphs/3r-REF --inMemory --port 22222 --securePort 22223 > /dev/null &");
```

Since that program takes quite some time to load, I would like to be able to notify the user when it is loaded so they can start using it (the program is OpenTripPlanner and it has a user interface accessible from a browser).

This particular program outputs a whole lot of info about the process and all, but when the program is done loading, it outputs a specific line, which looks like this

> 14:31:52.863 INFO (GrizzlyServer.java:130) Grizzly server running.

Since that line means that the program is ready to use, I figured  I could check the output and when I read a line that contains "Grizzly server running" I could notify the user.

The thing is that I don't know how I could do that.  I know `exec()` outputs the last line of the process, but that "Grizzly server running" line isn't the last one since the process doesn't stop after it is outputted (it only stops if we manually kill it).  I also know that `shell_exec()` returns the whole output, but again, the whole output isn't there since the process isn't done yet.

Do you guys have any idea on how to do that or an alternative I could use?

Thank you

**EDIT**

Based on [AbraCadaver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48775150/7507867), here's how I did

```
$cmd = "java -Xmx1G -jar /path/otp-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar --build /path/graphs/3r-REF --inMemory --port 22222 --securePort 22223"
exec($cmd . " > .grizzly &");
$ready = false;
while (!$ready) {
    if (strpos(file_get_contents('.grizzly'), 'Grizzly server running') !== false) {
        $ready = true;
    } else {
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

An issue I had was that (I think) strpos took too long and was asked to scan the output too often, that's why I added that 5 seconds sleep time (the whole process takes about 1 minute, so I though this was a fair time).  Now the output is only checked every 5 seconds and I get the expected result.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a better way but this should work.  Redirect to `.grizzly` and then continuously check the file for *Grizzly server running.*:

```
echo "Please wait...";
exec("java -Xmx1G -jar /path/otp-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar --build /path/graphs/3r-REF --inMemory --port 22222 --securePort 22223 > .grizzly &");

while(strpos(file_get_contents('.grizzly'), 'Grizzly server running.') === false){}
echo "Grizzly server running.";
```

Comment: When I try this, I get a `PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`.  Also, I got errors when I tried this without any already created file name `.grizzly` so I created one manually, but it is empty after the execution.

Answer (score 0):

`popen()` in 'r' mode allows you to read stdout of the process you run by chunk size you pass to `fread()` or until EOF is occurred.

```
$hndl = popen("java -Xmx1G -jar /path/otp-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar --build /path/graphs/3r-REF --inMemory --port 22222 --securePort 22223 > /dev/null &", 'r');
while ( $data = fread($hndl, 4096) ) {
     echo $data;
}
pclose($hndl);
```

Comment: You need to check for _Grizzly server running_ in the loop and `break`, but what if it reads to EOF before _Grizzly server running_ appears?